# Can a Jenkins Pipeline pass control to another Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, monorepo

We have a monorepo containing several related projects. Depending on which project triggered the build, a different set of projects need to be built. These projects all have their own Jenkinsfile which builds and deploys just that project.

I'd like to make a top-level Jenkinsfile which basically acts as a router. Have a small switch statement to build a list of projects to build in the right order and then kick off each of those Jenkinsfiles sequentially.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: i think its possible. you can use load(jenkinsfile) from other jenkinsfile to execute them.@PeterLoron I think shared Library Pipeline seems more suitable for your case though.

Comment: The `load` step can be used to load other pipeline files. Keep in mind that Blue Ocean and other visualizations may not be very useful if you are loading a different pipeline for each build. [This issue comment](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43749?focusedCommentId=319032&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-319032) looks like it may be relevant to your use case.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can create a jenkinsfile in a shared library and load it in your pipeline. From there you can do your check or switch and call other .groovy scripts (or jenkinsfiles) which are also in the shared library.